# Made reference from universal Windows 10 app to classic class library

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, class-library

Why can't you make a reference from a universal Windows  10 application to a classic class library? I know that you must use a universal Windows 10 class library for Windows 10 applications, but is there a class library that can have references to all types of applications or programs?

[image: Unable to add a reference to project 'WishLister.Client.Data'.]

I need to do this because I have began with a WPF program *(`WishLister.Client.Wpf`)* and made references to `WishLister.Client.Data` and `WishLister.Client.Models`. But now I will made a reference from `WishLister.Client.Uwa` to the class libraries `Data` and `Models`, but Visual Studio is unable to do that.

[image: Structure of my solution]

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Class Library.

It can be referenced from universal and classiс windows wpf app.